# Excel - simple graph X is date Y is time

Tags: excel

I have a simple data set in excel

A is column with date and time set to 00:00
B is column set with times

how to produce a simple line graph where
Y axis is the different dates from col A
X axis is times from col B

Back in the days  with office 97 :) I would select both columns from excel and hit the line graph - it was working perfect, but with office 2010 its mission impossible.

```
A                       | B
05/05/2016  00:00       |12:40
04/12/2016  00:00       |13:49
03/05/2016  00:00       |11:10
01/23/2016  00:00       |14:12
```

Comment: Why not change the format of `column A` to DATE SHORT

Comment: The title of the question (X is date) seems to contradict the question itself (X is times) If you did want the four dates to appear as labels on the x-axis rather than having a proportional scale, try converting them to text and using a line graph.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works perfectly in Excel 2010, too. The problem is the order of the columns. If you want to select the cells and create an XY scatter chart, the columns must have the X values on the left and the Y values on the right. Your data is arranged the wrong way around.

The Y data needs a column label, but leave the X data column header blank. Then you can simply select the data and insert an XY scatter chart.

[image]